# How do I stop EditForm submitting when updating a List item?

Tags: .net, blazor

I have a form where I ca add and remove products, almost like a basket. But when I add/remove a product from the list, the form submits.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
<EditForm EditContext="FormEditContext" method="post" OnValidSubmit="SubmitForm">
<MatSelectItem 
    Context="Product"
    @bind-Value="@formModel.Product"
    TValue="TariffProductQuoteViewModel"
    Items="AvailableProducts.ToList()"
    Disabled="!CanEdit">
     <ItemTemplate>
        @Product.ProductName
     </ItemTemplate>
</MatSelectItem>
    <MatButton OnClick="AddProduct">+ Add Product</MatButton>
</EditForm>
```

```
public void AddProduct()
{
    formModel.Items.Add(new Product()
    {
        ProductId = AvailableProducts.FirstOrDefault().Id,
        Product = AvailableProducts.FirstOrDefault(),
        Quantity = 1,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `Type` to `button` on `MatButton`, because default value is `submit` (which is also true for html button).

```
 <MatButton OnClick="AddProduct" Type="button">+ Add Product</MatButton>
```